# Oracle DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

This is a general question regarding Oracle PL/SQL. I have tried 
everything but have had no success with my commands. I am trying to
display a simply Text String using the DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE command.
I fail to understand what I am doing wrong, please help

```
       SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
       BEGIN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HELLO WORLD’);
       END;
```

This is not working for me

Comment: Which IDE are you using? SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 0):

By default, most tools do not configure a buffer for dbms_output to write to and do not attempt to read from that buffer after code executes. Most tools, on the other hand, have the ability to do so. In SQL*Plus, you'd need to use the command set serveroutput on [size N|unlimited]. So you'd do something like

```
SQL> set serveroutput on size 30000;
SQL> exec print_actor_quotes( <<some value>> );
```

In SQL Developer, you'd go to View | DBMS Output to enable the DBMS Output window, then push the green plus icon to enable DBMS Output for a particular session.

Answer (score 0):

If you are typing that into SQLplus, that is just building the command buffer.  Run what is in the buffer by typing a slash and press return:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2  dbms_output.put_line('efs');
  3  end;
  4  /
efs

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. enable the output and define the output size

`dbms_output.enable(100000);`

2. write output

`dbms_output.put_line('Hello world!');`

3. beware of max line length, which is 256 characters